# Composer libraries not working from callback function

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php, wordpress-rest-api, wp-api

I'm using wordpress and composer in it with some custom rest-api endpoints.

I setup the custom endpoint with `register_rest_route()` like that

```
register_rest_route( 'custom/v1', '/order', array(
  'methods' => 'POST',
  'callback' => 'create_order'
));
```

and in the callback `create_order` I'm trying to use a composer library but without success. I'm getting back a 500 error. In the rest of the website composer libraries are accessible without issue.

Anybody has an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Please specify the composer library.

Comment: How are you calling the function? The snippet of code you posted gives very little details. `register_rest_route` should be called through the `rest_api_init` action. See @Mustafa Uysal's example [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/)

Comment: @Jamie_D The library that i'm trying to use is that one https://packagist.org/packages/cocur/slugify

Comment: @Jamie_D I use it as you said through a `rest_api_init`

```add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
register_rest_route( 'custom/v1', '/order', array(
  'methods' => 'POST',
  'callback' => 'create_order'
));
})```

Comment: @Jamie_D in general I have no issues with the `register_rest_route`, my api works. The issue appeared when I tried to use a composer library in a  `register_rest_route ` callback.

Comment: Can we see some code from your `create_order` callback?

Comment: @Jamie_D For now I left it simple just for the sake of debugging. 


function create_order($request) {
   $slugify = new Slugify();
   return $slugify->slugify('Hello World');
}

Comment: I assume that the namespace `use Cocur\Slugify\Slugify;` is somewhere in your code or the library added to your PATH?

Comment: Yes the namespace is already there, in another place, but is there!

Comment: Definitely sounds scoping issue. Try it with `$slugify = new \Cocur\Slugify\Slugify();`

Comment: yes it works!! thank you very much @Jamie_D